# Some leaves of Iresine herbstii turning white, what do I do?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-care, leaves

I'm in the tropical region. I've got a new *Iresine herbstii* recently, I placed it outdoor under shade, so there is some sunlight but not direct sunlight.
Yesterday I found that some of the leaves are turning white, is it because of too much light or too little light(or other reasons)? I've now shifted the plant to a spot with lesser sunlight, but I'm not quite sure.
What do I do to prevent the leaves from turning white?

[image]

[image]